# Preventing DOM based XSS using ESAPI

Tags: java, security, xss, esapi

According to OWASP, to make dynamic updates to HTML in the DOM safe, we recommend

1. HTML encoding, and then
2. JavaScript encoding all untrusted input, as shown in
   these examples:
   `element.innerHTML = “<%=Encoder.encodeForJS(Encoder.encodeForHTML(untrustedData))%>”;`

There is a web application where the servlet receives the user input(received as an AJAX request) ,process the data and sends a text response which is used to change the DOM dynamically by setting  the value of an element(using `document.getElementById("elementID").innerHTML = data;`).

To prevent DOM based XSS is it required to escape the HTML and JavaScript using the ESAPI encoder as

```
String htmlEscapedStr=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(content);
String JSEscapedStr=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(htmlEscapedStr);
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(JSEscapedStr);
```

;

or is it safe to write the unencoded String to the stream

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `content` is plain text and you do not wish to ever contain HTML in your `content` itself. You do not need to encode for JavaScript as the value is **not** being *injected* into JavaScript, it is simply being used by JavaScript in a JavaScript context to set `innerHTML`. So the correct way is:

```
String htmlEscapedStr=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(content);
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(htmlEscapedStr);
```

The content type being left as `text/plain` is fine in this context as the application receiving the data (your webpage) does not have to interpret the content type itself as it is simply setting `innerHTML` to the returned value.

> or is it safe to write the unencoded String to the stream

If `content` contains any "untrusted" data (for "untrusted" read "from user input" or "from external source") then potentially it could contain script code as part of an XSS attack. If it is from a trusted source, but it is formatted as plain text then characters such as `<` could break the formatting of your output but would not cause a security issue. For example a mathematical expression such as `1 < 2 > 1.5` would be output as `1 1.5` in the browser.

Comment: content is a string containing html contents ,e.g String content=" <option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>";

Comment: In that case you will want to run `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(x)` on untrusted parts of `content` only. e.g. `content = "<option value=\"A\">" + ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(userInput) + "</option>"`.